# How to download public Google drive file using http request in android using Java?

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I have tried so many ways to download google drive public file but unable to find any answer?
If anyone knows how to do that please help me.

Note: without using Google drive api

Answer (score 0):

Most files (docs, sheets, presentation, etc..) can be downloaded by replacing **edit** with **export?format=** in the URL.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE-ID/edit
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE-ID/export?format=doc
```

There are a lot of formats available (pdf/doc/pptx/xlsx/csv/jpg/etc...)

The above solution usually works fine with pdfs, images, native google files and microsoft office files. However, if you are
trying to download another type of file, you can use the next URL.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE-ID
```

[More URL tricks here](https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/)

Comment: Not working, I have to download video.

Comment: The 2nd solution (https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=12345) is supposed to work fine with videos. I just tested it. What format are you using and how heavy is your video?

Comment: I wants to download mkv video file.

Comment: The problem is that your video is very heavy (389MB). If you open the URL in a browser, there is a message explaning the problem (https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1M97_Q2-P48fvM7yjYarTDggSsFQya2zJ) To get more help, I would recommend you to add "drive" and "google-apps-script" tags to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Tested with a google drive public link. Successfully downloaded.
    // Change the suffix of the Google Drive link from /edit to /export?format=csv
    // A sample link :
    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XYZ/export?format=csv
    // 
    public static boolean downloadWithRedirect(String downloadUrl, String storagePath){
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(downloadUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

        boolean redirect = false;

        // normally, 3xx is redirect
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                redirect = true;
        }

        if (redirect) {
            // get redirect url from "location" header field
            String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

            // get the cookie if need, for login
            String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            // open the new connnection again
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

            Log.i(TAG, "[downloadWithRedirect] Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);

        }

        input = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 1024 * 8);
        output = new FileOutputStream(storagePath);

        // Ensure output directory exists.
        File outputFile = new File(storagePath);
        FileUtil.mkDirs(new File(outputFile.getParent()));

        Log.i(TAG, "[download] url:" + downloadUrl + ", storagePath:" + storagePath + ", download stream length in bytes:" + conn.getContentLength());
        writeToOutputStream(input, output);

        return isFileValid(storagePath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "[downloadWithRedirect] Download failed. " + downloadUrl + " " + e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        try{if(output != null) output.close();}catch(Exception e){}
        try{if(input != null) input.close();}catch(Exception e){}            
    }
}

 private static void writeToOutputStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
    int length;
    if (is != null) {
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0x0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0x0, length);
        }
    }
    os.flush();
}
```